# Why does Mysql Xampp restart only when i run the mysqld.exe file manually?

Tags: mysql, xampp

1. I am using mysql-xampp v3.0.2 version.
2. while restarting the mysql server first it show me the running status and after 2or3s it stops running automatically.
3. So as of now i got a temporary solution like  going into xampp installation folder Xampp->mysql->bin->running the msqld.exe file.

i dont know whether it is the correct solution or is there any alternate solution to be made !!
 please suggest me

```
errorlog
120629 15:29:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120629 15:29:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120629 15:29:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
120629 15:29:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120629 15:29:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
120629 15:29:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file D:\xampp\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
120629 15:29:59  InnoDB: Setting file D:\xampp\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
120629 15:29:59  InnoDB: Log file D:\xampp\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
120629 15:30:00  InnoDB: Log file D:\xampp\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
120629 15:30:02  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have installed mysql as service then you can use `sc delete MySQL` to delete the service.. and then try again to start MySQL from xampp-control after system restart..

**Update**:

You may try uninstalling, system restart and then reinstalling the mysql service..

If problem remains, you may uninstall xampp completely and then reinstall the full package again..

You may [download xampp for windows here](http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-win32-1.8.1-VC9-installer.exe)..

Comment: no i have tried the same and restarted my system and tried to restart my mysql through xampp-control , again faced the same issue

Comment: what does `xampp\mysql\data\mysql_error.log` says..??

Comment: have pasted the error log above

Comment: is there solution

Comment: i have updated my reply..check if it helps.

Comment: i have reinstalled and now it is working fine